# How to clone the random access stream?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, stream, cross-platform, xamarin.uwp

I want to clone the IRandomAccessStream. I tried the CloneStream() to clone the stream but it not supported. Is there any way to clone the random access stream.

Thanks,
Santhiya A

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CopyTo method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting it to a `byte[]`  and then clone the `byte[]` in to new `IRandomAccessStream`.

```
    public async Task<IRandomAccessStream> CloneIRandomeAccessStream(IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream)
    {
        var reader = new DataReader(randomAccessStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
        byte[] bytes = new byte[randomAccessStream.Size];
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)randomAccessStream.Size);
        reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes.ToArray());
        IRandomAccessStream ClonerandomAccessStream = stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
        return ClonerandomAccessStream;
    }
```